# * vs .* in R with regexp

Tags: r, regex

Why does R (at least with tidyverse/stringr) recognize the following regexp: `*\.(png|jpg|jpeg)`? (in R due to character escaping one actually needs to write the string `"*\\.(png|jpg|jpeg)"`)

I think the correct regexp should be `.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg)` (writing in R `".*\\.(png|jpg|jpeg)"`))

When i introduce the first expression on e.g. regex101.com, it says that is is an illegal regexp. But R seems to parse it without issues.

Why?

Is the expression `*\.(png|jpg|jpeg)` a valid regular expression? If so, why does regex101 complain? If not, why does R accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the base R regex functions with the default TRE regex library, the `*` at the start of the pattern will get ignored. It is in line with how POSIX based regex engines behave, see [this `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/mGXvMn) (this tool uses POSIX BRE in the demo).

TRE regex engine being a POSIX based regex engine ignores the `*` at the start of the regex:

```r
> gsub("*\\.png$", "", "abc.png")
[1] "abc"
```

However, other NFA regex engines treat it as an error:

```r
> library(stringr)
> str_replace("abc.png", "*\\.png$", "")
Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX, context=`*\.png$`)
> gsub("*\\.png$", "", "abc.png", perl=TRUE)
Error in gsub("*\\.png$", "", "abc.png", perl = TRUE) : 
  invalid regular expression '*\.png$'
In addition: Warning message:
In gsub("*\\.png$", "", "abc.png", perl = TRUE) :
  PCRE pattern compilation error
        'quantifier does not follow a repeatable item'
        at '*\.png$'
```

`stringr` regex functions use the [ICU regex library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) and base R regex functions with `perl=TRUE` use the [PCRE regex library](https://www.pcre.org/) (**not `perl`**!)

Comment: This is useful to know but very confusing at the same time... So take home message: base R uses TRE, stringr uses ICU, and we can use PCRE with perl=True.

Comment: apart from my frustation on why there exists so many flavours of regex, what is a good source to undertand how R can treat different regexs with different engines? and a comparison. Thank you

Comment: @gota You know, `gsubfn` uses Tcl regex engine by default. It is very confusing when you try to use word boundaries there, `gsubfn("\\b\\d+(?:,\\d+)*\\b", ~ gsub(",", "", x, fixed=TRUE), "2,000.5MG/ML 2,500.6", backref=0)` does not work, but `gsubfn("\\y\\d+(?:,\\d+)*\\y", ~ gsub(",", "", x, fixed=TRUE), "2,000.5MG/ML 2,500.6", backref=0)` does. There is no one single complete resource for R regexps that I know, sorry.